# Get all available asset transforms

Tags: assets, image-transforms, macro, responsive-images

Is there a way to get all available image transforms in a template?
I would like to generate the `srcset` for responsive images programmatically.

I thought of creating a macro for that but haven't found any information about how to loop over all the registered image transforms.

Comment: You might want to get out the [ImageOptimize](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize) plugin; it has an OptimizedImages field that will pre-generate the `srcset` for you and create all of the images on Asset save time, so the frontend performance is optimal.

Comment: Another approach is is the [Picture](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-picture) plugin, where you define the transforms for a picture style in a config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Craft 4 PHP

```
$transforms = Craft::$app->getImageTransforms()->getAllTransforms();
```

#### Craft 3 PHP

```
$transforms = Craft::$app->getAssetTransforms()->getAllTransforms();
foreach($allTransforms as $transform){
    echo $asset->getUrl($transform->handle);
}
```

#### Craft 3 Twig

```
{% set allTransforms = craft.app.getAssetTransforms.getAllTransforms() %}
{% for transform in allTransforms %}            
    {{ asset.getUrl(transform.handle) }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Craft 2 PHP

```
$allTansforms = craft()->assetTransforms->getAllTransforms();
```

#### Craft 2 Twig

You'll need a plugin for this because you don't have access to that component

```
{% set allTransforms = craft.pluginHandle.getAllAssetTransforms %}
```

And in your `PluginVariable`

```
public function getAllAssetTransforms(){
    return craft()->assetTransforms->getAllTransforms();
}
```

Comment: I think for Craft 3 Twig, it should be {{ asset.getUrl(transform.handle) }}. I tried to edit your post, but I need to edit at least 6 characters ...

Comment: There is a API change in Craft 4, so it become `Craft::$app->getImageTransforms()->getAllTransforms();`